# Is the order of conditions in a where clause relevant if both sides are left joined entities?

Tags: sql, oracle

We have two queries on our database, where the only difference is the order of the conditions in an OR clause.

Queries of the same structure work fine on a similar data set on another database. We are working with `Oracle 12.2`.

The `Bestand` table has two connected entities where either one of them is always filled. In our example the Article is connected the `KbArticle` is always `null`. 
In one of our queries, we get all results for which the article `id` works in the other case we do not.
All of the Bestand entities fulfill the two last conditions `(cod_lbr = 12, flg_sperre = 0)`

```
SELECT bestand0_.*
FROM tbl_bestand bestand0_
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_kb_artikel customeror1_
ON bestand0_.id_kb_artikel=customeror1_.id_kb_artikel
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_artikel article2_
ON bestand0_.id_artikel          =article2_.id_artikel
WHERE (customeror1_.id_kb_artikel=3017874 OR article2_.id_artikel          =3017874)
AND bestand0_.cod_lbr            =12
AND NVL(bestand0_.flg_sperre,0)  = 0;
```

**yields results** [Link to Explain Plan](https://gerhofer.github.io/query-1.html)

```
SELECT bestand0_.*
FROM tbl_bestand bestand0_
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_kb_artikel customeror1_
ON bestand0_.id_kb_artikel=customeror1_.id_kb_artikel
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_artikel article2_
ON bestand0_.id_artikel          =article2_.id_artikel
WHERE (article2_.id_artikel          =3017874 OR customeror1_.id_kb_artikel=3017874)
AND bestand0_.cod_lbr            =12
AND NVL(bestand0_.flg_sperre,0)  = 0;
```

**yields no results** [Link to Explain Plan](https://gerhofer.github.io/query-2.html)

What makes absolutely no sense to me, as all of the results that we should get fulfill all of the statements in the where clause is that if you leave the last two conditions, the query returns the expected results, so if we modify our query to:

```
SELECT bestand0_.*
FROM tbl_bestand bestand0_
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_kb_artikel customeror1_
ON bestand0_.id_kb_artikel=customeror1_.id_kb_artikel
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_artikel article2_
ON bestand0_.id_artikel          =article2_.id_artikel
WHERE (article2_.id_artikel          =3017874 OR customeror1_.id_kb_artikel=3017874);
```

we get **results again** [Link to Explain Plan](https://gerhofer.github.io/query-3.html)

I would expect both queries to yield the same results, I can not understand why the order of the conditions should affect the outcome of the query in any way. 
Do we have some indices messed up here? 
It must be database specific as our queries work fine on another database, same version, with a similar set of data.

** UPDATE **

Unfortunately the query with the `AND OTHER_ID IS NULL` as @kfinity had the same problem as the queries above which makes absolutely no sense to me. After we disabled the *Adaptive Statistics Optimizer* that @Kuvick mentioned our queries both returned results again with the following explain plans:

[Explain plan Query 1](https://gerhofer.github.io/query-1-2.html) 
[Explain plan Query 2](https://gerhofer.github.io/query-2-2.html)

So turning that optimizer off solved our problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We identified the problem to be the Oracle setting OPTIMIZER_ADAPTIVE_PLANS and OPTIMIZER_ADAPTIVE_STATISTICS. By default after setting up the DB the first one is active and the second one is deactivated.

In our case both were activated. Right after deactivating OPTIMIZER_ADAPTIVE_STATISTICS (i.e. going back to the default settings) both queries returned the same results (as one would expect).
These settings can be checked with the follwing query:

```
SELECT * FROM v$parameter WHERE 1 = 1 AND LOWER(name) LIKE LOWER('optimizer_ad%') ORDER BY 1 DESC;
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your explain plans, it seems that the optimizer is rewriting your queries roughly like this:

First query:

```
select *
from tbl_bestand b
where ID_KB_ARTIKEL=3017874
  and COD_LBR=12 
  and ID_ARTIKEL IS NOT NULL
  and NVL(b.FLG_SPERRE,0)=0 
union all
select b.*
from tbl_bestand b
left outer join tbl_kb_artikel c
  on b.id_kb_artikel = c.id_kb_artikel
where COD_LBR=12 
  and ID_ARTIKEL=3017874
  and NVL(b.FLG_SPERRE,0)=0 
  and LNNVL(c.ID_KB_ARTIKEL=3017874) -- ie, ID_KB_ARTIKEL <> 3017874 or ID_KB_ARTIKEL is null
;
```

Second query:

```
select *
from tbl_bestand b
where ID_ARTIKEL=3017874 
  and COD_LBR=12 
  and ID_KB_ARTIKEL IS NOT NULL -- this is the problem, you didn't want this
  and NVL(b.FLG_SPERRE,0)=0 
union all
select b.*
from tbl_bestand b
left outer join tbl_kb_artikel a
  on b.id_kb_artikel = a.id_kb_artikel
where COD_LBR=12 
  and ID_KB_ARTIKEL=3017874
  and NVL(b.FLG_SPERRE,0)=0 
  and LNNVL(c.ID_ARTIKEL=3017874) -- ie, ID_ARTIKEL <> 3017874 or ID_ARTIKEL is null
;
```

So it's getting rid of one of the outer joins in each case (since you aren't filtering on any other columns in the outer joined tables), but it switches depending on which condition you put first.

But @scaisEdge is right - if you see the `IS NOT NULL` conditions, it's always turning one of the outer joins into an inner join. But I think you're also right, it seems like inconsistent optimizer behavior. I'm not sure why your other database isn't optimizing it the same way, but when I try your query with sample data, the explain plan just gets 2 `hash join outer`s.

Anyway, when putting left join columns in the WHERE clause, I usually explicitly ask for NULLs to avoid this kind of thing. Does this version work as expected?

```
SELECT bestand0_.*
FROM tbl_bestand bestand0_
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_kb_artikel customeror1_
ON bestand0_.id_kb_artikel=customeror1_.id_kb_artikel
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_artikel article2_
ON bestand0_.id_artikel =article2_.id_artikel
WHERE ((article2_.id_artikel=3017874 and bestand0_.id_kb_artikel is null)
    OR (customeror1_.id_kb_artikel=3017874 and bestand0_.id_artikel is null))
AND bestand0_.cod_lbr            =12
AND NVL(bestand0_.flg_sperre,0)  = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use the left join tables  columns  in where condition otherwsie this  work as  an inner join 
so the related  condition must be placed  in  ON clause

```
    SELECT bestand0_.*
    FROM tbl_bestand bestand0_
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_kb_artikel customeror1_ 
        ( ON bestand0_.id_kb_artikel=customeror1_.id_kb_artikel 
                 OR customeror1_.id_kb_artikel=3017874 )
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_artikel article2_
        ( ON bestand0_.id_artikel =article2_.id_artikel 
                  OR  article2_.id_artikel =3017874 )
    WHERE  bestand0_.cod_lbr            =12
    AND NVL(bestand0_.flg_sperre,0)  = 0;
```

Comment: but why does it work the other way around and on another table? 
I don't really have power over which alias is used - this is what's generated by hibernate.

In hibernate we explicitly use left joins and this is whats generated - I can't believe that hibernate is doing something wrong here now.

Comment: this should be related to the fact that the part of condition is true  and based  on OR is not needed the eval for others ..  . .. moving a left join condituion in where clause for this as  an INNER JOIN  so the value must match ...leaving the value in ON clause allower the join for null match ..

Comment: It does still not make sense for me as the query that yields result has the 
`WHERE (customeror1_.id_kb_artikel=3017874 OR article2_.id_artikel          =3017874)` whereas the query that does not yield results has 
`WHERE (article2_.id_artikel          =3017874 OR customeror1_.id_kb_artikel=3017874)`

and the customeror1_ object is the one that is null - so with your explanation only the query that does not yield results, should yield them and the other way around. 

Is there some optimizing happening here?

Comment: If one of the two condition   with involve the OR clause i true and the others not  .. then the change of position trigger or not the unexpected  inner join  .. without a proper dta sample in not possibile give you a definitive answer but this could be an explanation